# Share legend between two tikpicture environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

[image]

I have two tikzpictures with a bar-plot each in it. I want the two tikzpicture to share a common legend. The obvious way of clearing the legend in the first tikz and moving the legend of the second tikz into the middle of the two tikz-areas does not work.

The legends position seems to scale down the one tikzpicture. How can I make the one legend being centered between both tikzpictures without this weird scale-down effect.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}


\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
%        xlabel=Approachs,
        ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
%       legend style={font=\tiny, at={(0.05,0.97)},anchor=north west,legend columns=1},
        legend style={font=\small, at={(-0.1,0.-0.2)},anchor=north west,legend columns=2},
        symbolic x coords={A, B},
        ymax=100,
        ymin=30.0,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=+0.5,
        ymajorgrids=true,   
        bar width=0.3cm,    
        xmajorgrids=true    ,
        ytick={30,40,...,100},                  
    ]      


\addlegendentry{X}
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] plot coordinates {
        (A, 83.4)
        (B, 89.0)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[magenta,fill=magenta] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[orange,fill=orange] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\legend{}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
%        xlabel=Approachs,
        ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
        legend style={font=\small, at={(-0.6,0.-0.2)},anchor=north west,legend columns=3},
        symbolic x coords={A, B},
        ymax=100,
        ymin=30.0,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=+0.5,
        ymajorgrids=true,   
        bar width=0.3cm,    
        xmajorgrids=true    ,
        ytick={30,40,...,100},                  
    ]      


\addlegendentry{X}
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] plot coordinates {
        (A, 83.4)
        (B, 89.0)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[magenta,fill=magenta] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[orange,fill=orange] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  


\end{document}
```

Comment: You must  have had the code selected when you inserted the image I think, note that all your `[` and `]` has turned into `\[` and `\]`. Can you fix that?

Comment: You are right, some brackets did not belong there. I added a cleaned version of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no scaling involved, and the effect you're seeing isn't really weird. A `tikzpicture` is in the end just a big box, that is placed on the baseline similar to the letter `X`. The bottom of the first `tikzpicture` is the bottom of the ticklabels on the axis, but the bottom of the second one is the bottom of the legend.

But anyways, just place both `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture`, for example:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}    
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
%\centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{axis}[
        name=ax1,
        ybar,
%        xlabel=Approachs,
        ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
%       legend style={font=\tiny, at={(0.05,0.97)},anchor=north west,legend columns=1},
        legend style={font=\small, at={(-0.1,0.-0.2)},anchor=north west,legend columns=2},
        symbolic x coords={A, B},
        ymax=100,
        ymin=30.0,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=+0.5,
        ymajorgrids=true,   
        bar width=0.3cm,    
        xmajorgrids=true    ,
        ytick={30,40,...,100},                  
    ]      


\addlegendentry{X}
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] plot coordinates {
        (A, 83.4)
        (B, 89.0)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[magenta,fill=magenta] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[orange,fill=orange] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\legend{}


\end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
        at={(ax1.south east)},
        xshift=2cm,
        ybar,
%        xlabel=Approachs,
        ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
        legend style={font=\small, at={(0,-0.1)},anchor=north east,legend columns=3},
        symbolic x coords={A, B},
        ymax=100,
        ymin=30.0,
        xtick=data,
        enlarge x limits=+0.5,
        ymajorgrids=true,   
        bar width=0.3cm,    
        xmajorgrids=true    ,
        ytick={30,40,...,100},                  
    ]      


\addlegendentry{X}
\addplot[blue,fill=blue] plot coordinates {
        (A, 83.4)
        (B, 89.0)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[magenta,fill=magenta] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};

\addlegendentry{Y}
\addplot[orange,fill=orange] plot coordinates {
        (A, 85.2)
        (B, 90.6)       
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also have  a look at the `groupplots` library. See the `pgfplots` manual.